# Pgothic Title-Shaded st-Words Compiled with Lualatex in Which a Round 's' is Desired

Tags: fonts, color, luatex, shading, pgothic

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgothic}

\newcommand\titleshading[3]{

\newcommand\xoffset{0.3} % Horizontal positioning of the colored shading.
\newcommand\yoffset{-0.25} % Vertical positioning of the colored shading.

    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\newcommand\titleshadingA[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.18}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.2}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \titleshadingA{16}{0}{Breakf\/ast with pgothfamily}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Applying / to the st-word breakfast (`breakfa\/st`) in this environment does not seem to deliver a round s in the word "breakfast".

QUESTION: How may I produce a round 's', say, in the word "breakfast" when `pgothfamily` is used, color shading is involved, and the document is compiled with `lualatex`?

Thank you.

Comment: @Thérèse Let me check on that.

Comment: @Thérèse Sorry about the oversight. I'll edit it to match the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lualatex, I insert  `\/` ***after*** the `s`, as in `Breakfas\/t`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgothic}

\newcommand\titleshading[3]{

\newcommand\xoffset{0.3} % Horizontal positioning of the colored shading.
\newcommand\yoffset{-0.25} % Vertical positioning of the colored shading.

    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\newcommand\titleshadingA[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.18}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.2}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \titleshadingA{16}{0}{Breakfas\/t with pgothfamily}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

In pdflatex, I use `Breakfa{s}t`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgothic}

\newcommand\titleshading[3]{

\newcommand\xoffset{0.3} % Horizontal positioning of the colored shading.
\newcommand\yoffset{-0.25} % Vertical positioning of the colored shading.

    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\newcommand\titleshadingA[3]{
    \newcommand\xoffset{0.18}
    \newcommand\yoffset{-0.2}
    % Blur
    \foreach \x in {-0.1,0.1} {
        \foreach \y in {-0.1,0.1} {         
            \node[olive!62] at (#1em+\xoffset em+\x em,#2em+\yoffset em+\y em) {
                \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
            };
        }
    }

    % Main Shadow
    \node[olive!62] at (#1em+0.3em,#2em-0.2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1em,#2em) {
        \scalebox{1.75}{\Huge\pgothfamily{#3}} 
    };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]   
    \titleshadingA{16}{0}{Breakfa{s}t with pgothfamily}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This was compiled with lualatex? The reason I ask, is that when I try to compile it, the long s still results. But of course, that might be because of the older version of TexLive I am still using.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the confusion. Therese pointed out that I had specified `pdflatex` in my last sentence.

Comment: @mlchristians Let me look again.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mlchristians Please see my edit

Comment: Thank you very much! That works very nicely.